# convert dateformat from javascript to c#

Tags: c#, momentjs

In c# we have date format as 
day:dd(small letter)  Month:MM(capital)  year:yyyy(small)

But in moment.js date format is little different
day:DD(capital)  Month:MM(capital)  year:YYYY(capital)

So when I am sending date format from frontend (javascript) to backend (c#)
I am getting an exception due to mismatch in date format.

Is there any way in C# which converts moment dateformat to c# format?

Comment: It's a string so have you tried `String.ToUpper`?

Comment: Or `String.ToLower`, since the OP is sending it from JavaScript to C# :). But it still won't work because `MM` stays the same. You'll need to write a conversion function; there's really no standard for date format strings across platforms/languages.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I think you got the issue.
We don't have any such inbuilt conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe you want .NET's [`DateTime.ParseExact` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Extension metod for DateTime in C#

```
public static class FormatProviderExtension
{
   public static string ToMomentJSString(this DateTime arg, string format)
   {
       if (arg == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("arg");
       if (arg.GetType() != typeof(DateTime)) return arg.ToString();
       var date = (DateTime)arg;
       format = format
           .Replace("DD", "dd")
           .Replace("YYYY", "yyyy"); //etc.
       return date.ToString(format);
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
var d = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToMomentJSString("DD MM YYYY"));
Console.WriteLine(d.ToMomentJSString("DD"));
Console.WriteLine(d.ToMomentJSString("YYYY"));
```